# UITextField to hold/save value as I start typing without having me to hit the "done/save" button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I am looking for a code that allows me to have my textfield hold/save value as I start typing. The issue I am facing is that `UITextField` sets to the previously stored value if I choose to exit the view controller without hitting the done key on the keyboard. I want the `UITextField` to hold/save the value as I start typing so it holds the  value even if I exit the view controller.

Comment: *What have you tried*? Nobody here is going to write **all** this code for you - you must show that you have put forth some research effort. What have you tried previously? Why didn't that work?

Comment: Dismiss the keyboard programatically when the use navigates away.

Comment: I used -(BOOL)textField: (UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange) range replacementString: (NSString *) string

Comment: If you are exiting the view, and want the value of the text field to remain as it was before you left, then you need to store the value of the text field somewhere (user defaults, database...).

Comment: @Nick Yes sir, I am using the user defaults to set the email textField but it goes to Trap and my execution gets stuck without failing lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save the textField Value in NSUserDefault as you type. And retrieve from it.

in ViewDidLoad

```
-(Void) ViewDidLoad{

      NSString *textFieldValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"fieldValue"];

      myTextField.text = textFieldValue;
      myTextField.delegate = self;

}
```

//UITextField delegate

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:myTextField.text forKey:@"fieldValue"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this specifically on iOS, but I was able to get similar functionality in a Mac app that I was working on by implementing the `NSTextFieldDelegate`.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate>
```

Inside of the AppDelegate.m I implemented this part of the protocol:

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj{
```

This function would run every time text was entered into the field.

Hope this helps.